# Get facebook current location and hometown of public profile

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

how to get usernames and ids from this type of search? All the information is public here in this link. So how can i get a json data of the complete set of users.

https://www.facebook.com/search/108424279189115/residents/present/104057239629661/home-residents/intersect

In the link above, i have used 2 locations,

Hometown:Guntur
current location: Newyork

Comment: Graph Search has not still rolled out for everyone and there is not API to query the same. As of now, its just website only feature of Facebook

Comment: Is there any other way like page crawling and getting their names?

Comment: You can always perform web scrapping but that might just go out of Platform Policies

Comment: I just want to try this for learning. What do you suggest?

Comment: You may try [this](http://bit.ly/17iqEKU) but most probably... all this is outside of the policies of Facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written some script for downloading ID's for targeting purpose. I have used chrome dev tools to grab ID's of users.

JAVASCRIPT in Browser console helped me to achieve this.

Bookmarklet the javascript code attached here and open that link and click the bookmarklet. Thats it, Page scrolls for some time and a file gets downloaded which contains ID's of the user.

Its just a work around as we dont have an API for this.